Under what circumstances could a state's presidential election results he overturned?
Suppose that clear evidence were found proving that a state's presidential election results were affected by voting fraud. (This is a hypothetical scenario, and I am not referring to any election that has actually happened.) Under what circumstances could the election be overturned, replacing the fraudulently-chosen electors with those who would have been chosen had the election not been interfered with?

How could it be known what the election result would have been? Why is it assumed that had there been no fraud, the election would not have been won? And how many candidates were there? Every vote would have to be examined and a decision make about it. How do they know that the vote wouldn't have been the same without interference?

... and some voters don't make up their mind until the very last moment. How could anyone say which way they would have voted without the interference?

@WeatherVane If you've identified the fraudulent votes, can't you just do a recount without them?

OTOH, if it's not possible to determine the fraudulent votes, it seems that only a new election in that state could be a remedy.

@Barmar only if they were votes additional to the proper ones. It someone has tampered with the proper votes, then you would be discounting genuine votes. As you say, a new election is needed, especially if there are three candidates.

@WeatherVane I was thinking of the fraudulent votes being additional.

There may also be situations where you can determine that the fraud didn't affect the result. If there were 500 fraudulent votes (either changed or additional) and the margin of victory was 1000, they still would have won but by a smaller margin. E.g. Trump needed to "find" 11,000 votes in Georgia.

The timing matters.
After election day and before the electors are certified by the state, the validity of the election and disputes regarding its outcome can be litigated in the courts.
A state's Presidential vote is irrevocably fixed when the duly certified electors cast their electoral votes and send them to Congress.
Congress, at that point, could overturn the electoral votes it receives on the grounds that the electoral votes from a state weren't electoral votes cast by duly certified electors when it meets in early January after the post-election winners of the Congressional election have been sworn in.
Once Congress certifies the electoral vote in early January after the election, the winner of the Presidential election is absolutely final. Nothing can legality change the outcome of the election at that point, no matter how clear it is that the votes were miscounted and that the other candidate won that state.
Originally, this was governed by Article II, Section 1 of the U.S. Constitution, all of which has been superseded by later constitutional amendments, except the following language:

Each State shall appoint, in such Manner as the Legislature thereof
may direct, a Number of Electors, equal to the whole Number of
Senators and Representatives to which the State may be entitled in the
Congress: but no Senator or Representative, or Person holding an
Office of Trust or Profit under the United States, shall be appointed
an Elector. . . .
The Congress may determine the Time of chusing the Electors, and the
Day on which they shall give their Votes; which Day shall be the same
throughout the United States.

The 12th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution replaced a lot of the language omitted above with the following language:

The Electors shall meet in their respective states and vote by ballot
for President and Vice-President, one of whom, at least, shall not be
an inhabitant of the same state with themselves; they shall name in
their ballots the person voted for as President, and in distinct
ballots the person voted for as Vice-President, and they shall make
distinct lists of all persons voted for as President, and of all
persons voted for as Vice-President, and of the number of votes for
each, which lists they shall sign and certify, and transmit sealed to
the seat of the government of the United States, directed to the
President of the Senate; -- the President of the Senate shall, in the
presence of the Senate and House of Representatives, open all the
certificates and the votes shall then be counted; -- The person having
the greatest number of votes for President, shall be the President, if
such number be a majority of the whole number of Electors appointed;
and if no person have such majority, then from the persons having the
highest numbers not exceeding three on the list of those voted for as
President, the House of Representatives shall choose immediately, by
ballot, the President. But in choosing the President, the votes shall
be taken by states, the representation from each state having one
vote; a quorum for this purpose shall consist of a member or members
from two-thirds of the states, and a majority of all the states shall
be necessary to a choice. [And if the House of Representatives shall
not choose a President whenever the right of choice shall devolve upon
them, before the fourth day of March next following, then the
Vice-President shall act as President, as in case of the death or
other constitutional disability of the President. --]* The person
having the greatest number of votes as Vice-President, shall be the
Vice-President, if such number be a majority of the whole number of
Electors appointed, and if no person have a majority, then from the
two highest numbers on the list, the Senate shall choose the
Vice-President; a quorum for the purpose shall consist of two-thirds
of the whole number of Senators, and a majority of the whole number
shall be necessary to a choice. But no person constitutionally
ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of
Vice-President of the United States.

Portions to the 20th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution further modified the process:

Section 1. The terms of the President and the Vice President shall end
at noon on the 20th day of January, and the terms of Senators and
Representatives at noon on the 3d day of January, of the years in
which such terms would have ended if this article had not been
ratified; and the terms of their successors shall then begin.
Section 2. The Congress shall assemble at least once in every year,
and such meeting shall begin at noon on the 3d day of January, unless
they shall by law appoint a different day.
Section 3. If, at the time fixed for the beginning of the term of the
President, the President elect shall have died, the Vice President
elect shall become President. If a President shall not have been
chosen before the time fixed for the beginning of his term, or if the
President elect shall have failed to qualify, then the Vice President
elect shall act as President until a President shall have qualified;
and the Congress may by law provide for the case wherein neither a
President elect nor a Vice President elect shall have qualified,
declaring who shall then act as President, or the manner in which one
who is to act shall be selected, and such person shall act accordingly
until a President or Vice President shall have qualified.

The 23rd Amendment to the U.S. Constitution inserted the District of Columbia into the process stating in the pertinent part:

Section 1. The District constituting the seat of Government of the
United States shall appoint in such manner as the Congress may direct:
A number of electors of President and Vice President equal to the
whole number of Senators and Representatives in Congress to which the
District would be entitled if it were a State, but in no event more
than the least populous State; they shall be in addition to those
appointed by the States, but they shall be considered, for the
purposes of the election of President and Vice President, to be
electors appointed by a State; and they shall meet in the District and
perform such duties as provided by the twelfth article of amendment.


Where do the Electoral Count Act of 1887 and Electoral Count Reform and Presidential Transition Improvement Act of 2022 fit into this?

Basically, the 2022 Act amends the 1887 Act to reduce the discretion of Congress to consider anything other than the allegation that the electoral voters presented to Congress were not duly certified by the state in question.
